# Transfer a Windows 10 license to a new PC

Tags: windows-10, license, windows-activation

I have purchased a new PC and I would like to transfer Windows license from my old PC to the new one. I am using Windows 10 (which was upgraded from Win 8.1) on my older computer and  is activated with a licence linked to my Microsoft account. On my new PC, I have installed fresh copy of Win 10 using  Media Creation Tool. To activate Windows on the new PC, I attempted the following, but have not deactivated Windows on the old PC (deactivation procedure described [here](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-transfer-windows-10-license-new-computer-or-hard-drive))-

`Settings`  > `Update & Security`  > `Activation`> `Troubleshoot`> `I changed hardware on this device recently`> *Logged into my connected Microsoft account* > `This is the device I’m using right now` > `Activate`.

After performing the above, I am unable to activate Windows on my new PC. Please help me with the following-

1. Do I need to deactivate windows on older PC first?
2. Does Microsoft entitle users to transfer licenses to new PC?
3. Is there anything else which I have missed out?

If this helps- `slmgr -dli` gives the following

[image]

Comment: “After performing the above, I am unable to activate Windows on my new PC.” - Please provide details.  It should be as simple as entering the product key on the new computer

Comment: You should be able to remove and de-activate the device to transfer the license via your [Microsoft account > Devices](https://account.microsoft.com/devices/) > click on applicable device > More Actions > Remove <device>

Comment: @John The screenshot shows "retail".

Comment: Then you can move the license (but only operating on one computer at one time)

Comment: I have deactivated windows on the older PC, but that did not helped. I have asked a followup question at https://superuser.com/questions/1503910/unable-to-reactivate-windows-on-a-new-pc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The process was rather simple, but I could not find the solution anywhere on the internet. The process detailed on [How to transfer a Windows 10 license to a new PC or hard drive](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-transfer-windows-10-license-new-computer-or-hard-drive) did not helped me.

I contacted windows support and they told me that I can activate Windows 10 on my new PC using the Windows 8.1 key which I used to upgrade to Win 10; this worked for me after deactivating Windows 10 on older PC using `slmgr /upk`.