# Unable to reactivate windows on a new PC

Tags: windows-10, license, windows-activation

I had earlier asked a question [here on SU.SE](https://superuser.com/questions/1503026/transfer-a-windows-10-license-to-a-new-pc). It was suggested to me that I should firstly deactivate windows on older PC and then try to activate windows on the  new PC. I have deactivated windows on the older PC by `slmgr /upk`, but I am unable to activate windows on the new PC.

I have followed `Activation`> `Troubleshoot`> `I changed hardware on this device recently`> **Unable to Activate Windows** >  `See other devices linked to your Microsoft account`, I get the following message (attached as image). In the attached image my windows is listed, but mentions as **Windows isn't Activated** and I do not get the option to select the windows.

Have I followed a wrong procedure? What should I do next?

[image]

PS: I have a Retail license of Windows

[image]

Comment: The only type of license you can transfer to a different computer is a Retail license. Is that the kind of license you have? If so, you have a product key; use that. If not, you can't activate Windows on the new computer until you buy a license for it.

Comment: @IsayReinstateMonica - I have a retail license https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTP2X.jpg

Comment: Please do not only respond in the comments. Instead, [edit] the post with this information.

Comment: Call Microsoft Support and they will activate your Retail Licence

Answer (score 0):

To add on @I say Reinstate Monica 's comment, note that if you use the "I changed hardware" for 3 times, it won't allow the 4th time.

Comment: Any Microsoft docs that say this???

Comment: I could not find any just this one "If you have a full retail copy of Windows 10, you can transfer it as many times as you want." >>>>>https://www.groovypost.com/howto/transfer-windows-10-license-new-pc/